# Android Activity en pantalla Completa

Tags: android

Al momento de crear una nueva Activity Quedan espacios que el boton no ocupa necesito que esos espacios sean ocupados

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Necesitas mostrar tu código si esperas una buena respuesta, no podemos adivinar como haces lo que haces.

Comment: agrega  `android:layout_marginLeft="-64dp"` a las propiedades de tu drawer.

Comment: ya modifique la pregunte para que sea mas fácil de entender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el layout raiz quitale los padding:

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```